# import { h } from preact - when is it necessary

Tags: preact

I'm currently building a Preact PWA with the CLI.

My understanding was that wherever I have a component defined with JSX, I need to have `import { h } from 'preact'` at the top of the file.

I removed all instances of that import statement, yet the application still runs and builds perfectly fine.

Can someone set me straight here, as I'm a little confused now - perhaps there is some magic going on behind the scenes somewhere?

Answer (score 25):

When you write a jsx syntax like

```
render() {
  return <div id="abc">Hello World</div>
}
```

Behind the screen it will be converted to

```
render() {
  return h('div', { id: 'abc' }, 'Hello World')
}
```

So, when it is necessary to import `h`?

The answer is **Every time you use a jsx syntax**. JSX is not part of the JavaScript spec, it have to be converted to the equivalent function call. Which in preact using `h` or in react using `React.createElement`.

As you mention, we can make the `import` automatic by using additional `babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic` plugin.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [],
  'plugins': [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx', { pragma: 'h' }],
    ['babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic', {
      module: 'preact',
      import: 'h',
      export: 'h',
    }],
  ],
}
```

Learn more at: https://github.com/jmm/babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after some digging around I see there is a babel-config in the preact-cli node module, which is adding the following code:

`plugins: [
  [require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx'), { pragma: 'h' }], 
  [require.resolve('babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic'), {
    module: 'preact',
    export: 'h',
    import: 'h'
  }]
]`

It appears to mean imports of `h` are automatic and not explicitly required. Would be nice it this were mentioned in their documentation!

Comment: There is indeed documentation on this. https://github.com/developit/preact#import-what-you-need

Comment: Updating @rbenvenuto's comment: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/tree/e026d9e1a871a3f84fb88a499168b4af083673f6#import-what-you-need